# Form via template string PHP and VueJS CDN

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js

I made a web application using VueJS CDN, I am not using CLI. In this application I created a contact form, which is inserted inside the template string, like this below:

```
const Contato = {
            template: `<!-- contact-form-box start -->
            <section class="contact-form-box flex-min-height-box" style="background-image:url(assets/images/backgrounds/pexels-photo-1287145.jpeg)">
                <div class="bg-overlay"></div>
                <!-- flex-min-height-inner start -->
                <div class="flex-min-height-inner">
                    <!-- contact-form-container start -->
                    <div class="contact-form-container">
                        <!-- container start -->
                        <div class="container small top-bottom-padding-100 form-box">
                            <h4 class="small-title-oswald text-color-4 text-center">Envie sua mensagem por aqui!</h4>
                            <!-- flex-container start -->
                            <form action="/contato.php" class="flex-container top-padding-90" method="post" name="formobrsv" id="send_form">
                                
                                <!-- column start -->
                                <div class="four-columns">
                                    <div class="content-right-margin-10 input-box">
                                        <input type="text" name="first_name" v-model="first_name" id="first_name" required class="form-input pointer-small">
                                        <label for="first_name" class="form-label">Primeiro nome</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- column end -->
                                <!-- column start -->
                                <div class="four-columns">
                                    <div class="content-left-right-margin-5 input-box">
                                        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" required class="form-input pointer-small">
                                        <label for="last_name" class="form-label">Ultimo nome</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- column end -->
                                <!-- column start -->
                                <div class="four-columns">
                                    <div class="content-left-margin-10 input-box">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required class="form-input pointer-small">
                                        <label for="email" class="form-label email-label">Email</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- column end -->
                                <!-- column start -->
                                <div class="twelve-columns input-box message-input">
                                    <textarea name="message" id="message" required class="form-input pointer-small"></textarea>
                                    <label for="message" class="form-label">Mensagem</label>
                                </div><!-- column end -->
                                <!-- column start -->
                                
                                <div class="twelve-columns text-center top-padding-90">
                                
                                    <button type="submit" name="BTenvia" class="border-btn-box pointer-large">
                                        
                                            <span class="border-btn"  data-text="enviar">enviar</span>
                                         
                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                                </div><!-- column end -->
                            </form><!-- flex-container end -->
                        </div><!-- container end -->`
        }
```

So I created a page called contato.php where I try to do the sending process to the email, but it's not happening. I click the submit button and nothing happens, what's happening? How should I do it?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['BTenvia'])) {

    
    $primeiro_nome = $_REQUEST['first_name'];
    $segundo_nome = $_REQUEST['last_name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST ['email'];
    $mensagem = $_REQUEST['message'];

    $email_remetente = "contact@teste.com.br";

    $email_destinatario = "contact@teste.com.br";
    $email_reply = "$email";
    $email_assunto = "Contato pelo Site";

    $email_conteudo = "Nome: $primeiro_nome \n";
    $email_conteudo .= "Telefone: $segundo_nome \n";
    $email_conteudo .= "Email: $email \n";
    $email_conteudo .= "Mensagem: $mensagem \n";

    $email_headers = implode ( "\n",array ( "From: $email_remetente", "Reply-To: $email_reply", "Return-Path: $email_remetente","MIME-Version: 1.0","X-Priority: 3","Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" ) );

    if (mail ($email_destinatario, $email_assunto, nl2br($email_conteudo), $email_headers)){ 
        echo "</b>E-Mail enviado com sucesso!</b>"; 
        } 
        else{ 
        echo "</b>Falha no envio do E-Mail!</b>"; } 
}


?>
```

Comment: Press the F12 key and look in the browser console for any errors - and try to fix them.

Comment: @IVOGELOV The problem is that the console doesn't show me any errors when I click the button!

Comment: If there are no errors, then the submit button should trigger a form submission - unless something has attached event handlers to the form or to the button and prevents the default action of submission. The code looks fine so you must troubleshoot on your PC - or create a SandBox to reproduce the issue.